# how to get the list of keys in a Parse.com query?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

Is there any option to get only the list of existing keys instead of getting all of them in a query?

i'm using **PFQueryTableViewController** to build my Table View

i have a **Parse.com** class that contains list of keys which can duplicate themselves

need to build table view that show only the list of unique keys from that class

can i do that using parse querying methods while overriding **func queryForTable() -> PFQuery**

Using swift for ios

Answer (score 1):

Here you can find documentation: [Basic Queries](https://www.parse.com/docs/ios/guide#queries-basic-queries)